# How to configure/customize emacs? (key bindings, windows nav bar, etc)

Tags: emacs

OLD QUESTION: How To Kill Characters Before The Cursor in Emacs?
OLD COMMENTS: According to a reference, it should simply be the delete key, but the delete key as well as the C-d commands kill the character AFTER the cursor

EDITTED

I am running emacs via cli. Which file do I edit and how do I change key bindings for commands?
As for the nav/window bar, I was reading a link and here is a code snippet in it:

```
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %m/%d %C%a "
```

What does the last line mean? How do I even begin to read it? What language is it written in?

I appreciate all responses!

Comment: That's very weird. What does it say when you do `C-h k DELETE`? Also does calling `M-x backward-delete-char` do what you'd expect?

Comment: This might be relevant to you http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceKey

Comment: I'm sorry. I sorta isolated the cause although I'm not sure how to change it. I'm following an online course and we were instructed to download an install script that installed emacs and loaded config files or something. So I started emacs without adding '-Q' which made the DEL key kill the character infront. As I understand it, '-Q' tells emacs to run on defaults or something.

Comment: Sorry for double post. Let me change the question and then all answers welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration file for emacs is the `~/.emacs` file. This file will be loaded and executed everytime you start emacs. You can check which file is used by running `M-x describe-variable RET user-init-file`. If the file does not exist you can simply create it.

To bind commands to keys you can use the `global-set-key` function. The following will bind control+h to the "backspace" command (put the following in the init file).

```
(global-set-key (kbd “C-h”) ‘backward-delete-char)
```

As for you code snippet it is not related to emacs, but seems to have to do with GNU Screen. See http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/560

Answer (score 0):

Backspace? I.e. the key above Return. There's more detailed advice here:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceKey